# List of subfolders names, folder path and date modified field

Tags: r, subdirectory, last-modified

Need to write a piece of code in R that'll create a list specifying:

- Names of subfolders with a pre-set depth (e.g. 2 levels down)
- Path
- Date modified

I've tried to use the following generic function but had no luck:

```
list.files(path, pattern=NULL, all.files=FALSE,
    full.names=FALSE)
dir(path, pattern=NULL, all.files=FALSE,
    full.names=FALSE)
```

Would very much appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your are missing is the `recursive = TRUE` parameter in `list.files()`

One possible solution could be to list all files first and then limit the output to 2 levels accordingly.

```
files <- list.files(path = "D:/cmder/", recursive = TRUE)
```

Since R represents paths using "/" a simple example could be to remove everything that has more than 3 slashes if you need a depth of 2.

```
files[!grepl(".*/.*/.*/.*", files)]
```

Be careful on windows as you might see a back slash "\" there sometimes, only if your path information comes from something different that R itself, e.g. a csv import.

My `grepl()` statement can probably be improved as I'm not an expert there.

Comment: For the date modified information you can use file.info(files) but then you need to set the parameter full.names = TRUE in file.list(). And you'd need to extend the grepl() statement to look for more slashes eventually.